# Insert with csv in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My split function is

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString](@String varchar(8000), @String2 varchar(8000),      @String3 varchar(8000))
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000), items2 varchar(8000), items3 datetime)
as
begin
declare @idx int
declare @slice varchar(8000)
declare @idx2 int
declare @slice2 varchar(8000)
declare @idx3 int
declare @slice3 varchar(8000)
declare @Delimiter char(1) = ','

select @idx = 1
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return

select @idx2 = 1
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return

select @idx3 = 1
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return

while @idx!= 0 AND @idx2!= 0 AND @idx3!= 0
begin
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
    if @idx!=0
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)
    else
        set @slice = @String

    set @idx2 = charindex(@Delimiter,@String2)
    if @idx2!=0
        set @slice2 = left(@String2,@idx2 - 1)
    else
        set @slice2 = @String2

    set @idx3 = charindex(@Delimiter,@String3)
    if @idx3!=0
        set @slice3 = left(@String3,@idx3 - 1)
    else
        set @slice3 = @String3

    if(len(@slice)>0 AND len(@slice2)>0 AND len(@slice3)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Items,items2,items3) values(@slice, @slice2, (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@slice3 AS DATETIME), 106), ' ', '-') ))

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)
    set @String2 = right(@String2,len(@String2) - @idx2)
    set @String3 = right(@String3,len(@String3) - @idx3)
    if (len(@String) = 0 AND len(@String2) = 0 AND len(@String3) = 0) break


end
return
end
```

it takes in 3 input two `varchar` and one `datetime`. When I test this function with this

```
select * From dbo.SplitString
(
 'Comments1,Comments2,Comments3,',
 'UserName1,UserName2,UserName3,', 
 '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM,2/2/2013 12:00:00 AM,3/3/2013 12:00:00 AM,'
)
```

I get proper values

```
Comments1       UserName1       2013-01-01 00:00:00.000
Comments2       UserName2       2013-02-02 00:00:00.000
Comments3       UserName3       2013-03-03 00:00:00.000
```

Now I am using this to insert

```
    SELECT @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    DECLARE @Comments = 'Comments1,Comments2,Comments3,'
    DECLARE @UserName = 'UserName1,UserName2,UserName3,', 
    DECLARE @EntryDate = '1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM,2/2/2013 12:00:00 AM,3/3/2013 12:00:00 AM,'

    INSERT INTO dbo.EventActivationComments
    (
        EventID,
        Comments,
        UserName,
        EntryDate
    )
    (
        SELECT @ID, * FROM dbo.SplitString(@Comments,@UserName,@EntryDate)
    )
```

But I get an error on insert

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure InsertNewEvent, Line 0
>   Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how a string in your input is interpreted as `DateTime` in SQL Server.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependant** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am really very confused now. I am a developer and my work has been very little on database side. Could be be little more specific on what I need to change

Comment: You need to change the format of your date strings to match an appropriate date format.  The datetime field can't accept them as they are.

Comment: do you mean change this line to match the appropriate date format (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@slice3 AS DATETIME), 106), ' ', '-')